# getUserMedia returning stream with audio when there is no audio device

Tags: html, webrtc, getusermedia

I have a case when I turned off all media (camera and microphone) but `navigator.getUserMedia with` constraints of `{audio: yes, video: no}` successfully return a stream and furthermore `stream.getAudioTracks().length` return 1 which is highly strange because there are no device connected to produce this audio. If I put this stream to audio tag I only hear a weak white noise (in opposite to if I plug in microphone when I clearly hear myself).

What can be the reason for such a strange behavior?

Comment: what operating system are you using? I know on Linux Chrome uses pulse for audio and it could be attaching to an Audio Output monitor and not a microphone(because it could not find one).

Comment: @BenjaminTrent, this happens in both Linux and Windows

Comment: Which browser? It sounds like they way it is designed honestly.

Comment: We are using only Chrome here.

Comment: This is not happening with me on Chrome in Windows. If I disable my audio recording device, getuermedia fails when trying to get audio only. Are you sure that all recording devices are disable/not available?

Comment: @BenjaminTrent If I disable it in OS settings then yes, this does not happening, but if just unplug my external microphone from motherboard slot then it would still create stream with 1 audio track.

Comment: Hmmm...This may be a bug or a feature update request for chrome.